# Derivative Problem: $e^{-x}f(x)=2+\int{\sqrt{t^{4}+1}}dt$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function defined on $(-1,1)$ such that
>   $e^{-x}f(x)=2+\int_0^x{\sqrt{t^{4}+1}}\;\mathrm{d}t$ for all $x$ belonging to
>   $(-1,1)$ and $g(x)$ be its inverse function.

How to find the value of $g'(2)$ (the derivative of $g(x)$ at $x=2$)?

I tried writing $f(g(x))=x$ and then took derivative on both sides of original equation. But it's not working. I think I'm missing something important.

And please don't use hyper-geometric functions.

Comment: See also: [$e^{-x}f(x)=2+ \int_0^x\sqrt{t^4+1}dt$ function for finding the inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2879394)