# $e^{-x}f(x)=2+ \int_0^x\sqrt{t^4+1}dt$ function for finding the inverse

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let f be the real-valued function defined on the interval $(-1,1)$ such that $e^{-x}f(x)=2+ \int_0^x\sqrt{t^4+1}dt$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and let $f^{-1}$ be the inverse function of $f$. Then find the value of $(f^{-1})'(2)$.

This is my step

1-$f(x)=y$

2-$f^{-1}(y)=x$

3-$f^{-1}(x)=y$

4-$f^{-1}(x)'=\frac{dy}{dx}$

5-  $y=f(x)=2e^{x}+e^{x} \int_0^x\sqrt{t^4+1}dt$

6-  $y'=2e^{x}+e^{x} \int_0^x\sqrt(t^4+1)dt+e^x\sqrt{x^4+1}$

I am lost after this step, please help me as I have jolted down the step.

Comment: Find $f(0)$ , then find an expression of $f'(x)$ and find $f'(0)$.Then consider the expression: $$(f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$. Differentiate it .

Comment: See also: [Derivative Problem: $e^{-x}f(x)=2+\int{\sqrt{t^{4}+1}}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325122)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $f(0)=2$ and
$$-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=\sqrt{x^4+1}$$
at $x=0$ gives $-2+f'(0)=1$ then
$$(f^{-1})'(2)=\dfrac{1}{f'(0)}=\dfrac13$$